# Преобразование текста в цифры

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, byte

Я нашел код, который конвертирует строку в цифры, когда я запускаю код в терминале через python3, он выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 49, in <module>
    numberOutput = int(bit_list_to_string(string_to_bits(inputString)),2) #1976620216402300889624482718775150
  File "test.py", line 31, in string_to_bits
    map(chr_to_bit, s)
  File "test.py", line 30, in <listcomp>
    return [b for group in
  File "test.py", line 29, in chr_to_bit
    return pad_bits(convert_to_bits(ord(c)), ASCII_BITS)
  File "test.py", line 14, in pad_bits
    assert len(bits) <= pad
AssertionError
```

Когда я запускаю программу через пайтон(он версии 2.7), код работает корректно

Code:

```
BITS = ('0', '1')
ASCII_BITS = 8

def bit_list_to_string(b):
    """converts list of {0, 1}* to string"""
    return ''.join([BITS[e] for e in b])

def seq_to_bits(seq):
    return [0 if b == '0' else 1 for b in seq]

def pad_bits(bits, pad):
    """pads seq with leading 0s up to length pad"""
    assert len(bits) <= pad
    return [0] * (pad - len(bits)) + bits

def convert_to_bits(n):
    """converts an integer `n` to bit array"""
    result = []
    if n == 0:
        return [0]
    while n > 0:
        result = [(n % 2)] + result
        n = n / 2
    return result

def string_to_bits(s):
    def chr_to_bit(c):
        return pad_bits(convert_to_bits(ord(c)), ASCII_BITS)
    return [b for group in
            map(chr_to_bit, s)
            for b in group]

def bits_to_char(b):
    assert len(b) == ASCII_BITS
    value = 0
    for e in b:
        value = (value * 2) + e
    return chr(value)

def list_to_string(p):
    return ''.join(p)

def bits_to_string(b):
    return ''.join([bits_to_char(b[i:i + ASCII_BITS])
        for i in range(0, len(b), ASCII_BITS)])

inputString = "attack at dawn"
numberOutput = int(bit_list_to_string(string_to_bits(inputString)),2) #1976620216402300889624482718775150

bitSeq = seq_to_bits(bin(numberOutput)[2:]) #[2:] is needed to get rid of 0b in front
paddedString = pad_bits(bitSeq,len(bitSeq) + (8 - (len(bitSeq) % 8))) #Need to pad because conversion from dec to bin throws away MSB's
outputString = bits_to_string(paddedString) #attack at dawn
```

Какие корректировки внести, чтобы код работал исправно?

Comment: Извините если не в тему. Не пробовали использовать встроенный модуль [decimal — Decimal fixed point and floating point arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)

Comment: А что код делает? Смотрели в какой момент поведение кода начинает отличаться от аналогичного на py2?

Comment: Проблема была в делении в функции ef convert_to_bits(n), в результате такой работы функции получается список из вещественных чисел. Всем спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переписал алгоритм, посмотрите:

```
ASCII_BITS = 8

def bins_str(text):
    def to_bin(c):
        return bin(ord(c))[2:].zfill(ASCII_BITS)

    return ''.join(to_bin(c) for c in text)

# 1976620216402300889624482718775150
inputString = "attack at dawn"

bin_str = bins_str(inputString)
print(bin_str)          # 0110000101110100011101000110000101100011011010110010000001100001011101000010000001100100011000010111011101101110
print(int(bin_str, 2))  # 1976620216402300889624482718775150
```

И обратный алгоритм:

```
def int_to_text(number):
    bin_str = bin(number)[2:]
    pad = '0' * (ASCII_BITS - len(bin_str) % ASCII_BITS)
    bin_str = pad + bin_str
    
    chars = []
    for i in range(0, len(bin_str), ASCII_BITS):
        bin_part = bin_str[i: i + ASCII_BITS]
        c = chr(int(bin_part, 2))
        chars.append(c)

    return ''.join(chars)

print(int_to_text(1976620216402300889624482718775150))  # attack at dawn
```

---

**PS.**

- `ord(...)` - возвращает код символа
- `bin(...)` - возвращает строку в двоичном представлении с префиксом `0b`
- `bin(...)[2:]` - возвращает новую строку начиная с третьего символа
- `....zfill(8)` - возвращает новую строку, дополняя слева недостающие 0
- `''.join(...` - объединяет элементы в одну строку, т.е. конкантенация

Наглядно:

```
print(ord('A'))                    # 65
print(bin(ord('A')))               # 0b1000001
print(bin(ord('A'))[2:])           # 1000001
print(bin(ord('A'))[2:].zfill(8))  # 01000001
```